# camada DAO com duas tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, arquitetura-de-software, design-pattern

A minha dúvida ao trabalhar com a camada `DAO` segua a seguinte:

Até onde me informei, cada tabela seria referente a um objeto `DAO`. Mas suponhamos que seja necessário fazer uma consulta com `select / JOIN` ou seja, que a mesma retorne dados de mais de uma tabela em uma única consulta.

Para este caso, o objeto `DAO` de uma tabela poderia buscar dados de outra tabela?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mantenha-se simples, é a melhor coisa para manutenções futuras de uma aplicação!

Se você precisar fazer um `join` com outra tabela, escolha em que `DAO` tem mais sentido efetuar este relacionamento.

Por exemplo, eu tenho uma `classe` chamada `ClientDAO` e a outra chamada `AddressDAO`, e quero relacionar o cliente aos seus endereços, que podem ser vários, não fara sentido algum efetuar este relacionamento na classe `ClientDAO`, porque quem faz a abstração de endereços e a `AddressDAO`.

Sendo assim só passar as propriedades da camada `Client` para o `AddressDAO`.

```
related(Client $Client)
```